# Bash Loop print and reduce number for counter

Tags: bash, loops, scripting

I am trying to create a small bit of code in Bash where a integer is read, printed, then subtracted by 1 and repeats when the integer reaches 0.

The problem is that I am unable to reassign the integer $Number after each loop. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
if [ $Number -ne 0 -o $Number -eq 0 2>/dev/null ]
then
    while [ $Number -gt 1]
    do
    printf "$Number\n"
    $Number=$Number-1
done
echo "$Number"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash the [arithmetic expansions](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) can be done using double paranthesis, or `expr` or `let`.

**Example**

```
while [[ $Number -gt 1 ]]
do
    printf "$Number\n"
    ((Number -= 1 ))
done
```

---

**Test**

```
$ cat prog.sh
Number=5
while [[ $Number -gt 1 ]]
do
    printf "$Number\n"
    ((Number -= 1 ))
done

$ bash prog.sh
5
4
3
2
```

Comment: I agree that `((...))` and `let` can be used for arithmetic evaluation, but I doubt that backtick have anything to do with it. As far as I know, backtick is the older form of `$(...)` which is command expansion. Can you please give an example of backtick expression that does arithmetic evaluation without executing a command (like `expr` or `let`,...)?

Comment: @oliv Backtick along with `expr`. From TLDP docs, *Arithmetic expansion with backticks (often used in conjunction with expr)*. Please see the lined doc for example

Comment: I tried to execute this code, sh ./test 3, but the command didn't work properly. The output would go into an infinite loop and would say not found.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I saw the TLDP page and the backtick is for executing the `expr` command. My point is your answer would be more correct if you would say:  _In bash the arithmetic expansions can be done using double paranthesis, or_ expr _or let_.

Comment: @oliv Good point. I have corrected my answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @user3807468 Please see the test I have added.

Comment: My syntax was just wrong in general. FUUUUUUU
Thanks though, through my unix class, I learned deeply how bad I suck at scripting languages and how much I feel so weak :(